# How can I use a modern keyboard with the Panasonic JB 3000?

Tags: keyboard

I still own my very first computer - a [Panasonic JB 3000](http://messui.the-chronicles.org/comp/national.pdf).  The keyboard it came with now has many faulty keys.  It has reached the stage where I can no longer use the computer, because I can't type.  I would like to buy (or possibly even solder up) an adapter which will allow me to use a more modern keyboard with the computer.  Unfortunately the computer and its existing keyboard uses a 6 Pin DIN connector:

[image: Panasonic JB-3000 keyboard]
[image: Panasonic JB-3000 Din-6 keyboard connector]

The JB-3000 was released around 1983 and was a PC clone.  However it seems that the IBM-PC it was based off used a 5 Pin DIN for its keyboards.  It also looks like the JB-3000's keyboard doesn't match the layout of the 84 model F keyboard in use with the original IBM-PC.

My questions are:

**Does anyone know anything about these 6 Pin DIN keyboards?**

**Would it be electrically compatible with a any other type of keyboard, for example the Model F, or the Model M?**

**Is there any way I can adapt another keyboard to run with my JB 3000?**

Comment: This looks like a good question for http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why don't you disassemble the keyboard and repair what's broken? It's useless anyway in its current state. Might be easier that getting the info you're looking for, or a suitable replacement keyboard.

Comment: As suggested I have cross posted to http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/972/2043

Comment: The suggestion was not to cross-post, that is seriously frowned upon.  Pick a site and post there.  If you don't get an answer after a reasonable time, close or delete that question and repost on another site.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an answer to the third part of your question sorry but:

You can buy 6pin to Ps2 converters on ebay. That way you can simply plug in a PS2 keyboard

example: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/6-Pin-Mini-Din-PS-2-Male-to-5-Pin-Din-AT-Female-Keyboard-Adapter-Convertor-/291583611577?hash=item43e3bcd2b9

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the correct adapter. The one on ebay is for 5 pin DIN. But Luke needs a 6 pin DIN.

Comment: It most certainly is. My google fu has indeed let me down.

Comment: I also have no idea how and where to find it. It looked through all the lists at pinouts.ru and couldn't find anything suitable. So I guess retrocompuing.stackexchange.com might really be the best place to search on.

Comment: It should be possible to solder the cable from a PS2 computer (6 pole mini din) but I can't find the wiring diagram for the 6 pin DIn connector. The PS2 wiring diagram is on its wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port

Comment: Though it has 6 pins, I am not so convinced that it is using the same data protocol.

Comment: The JB-3000 dates from 1983.  The PS/2 keyboard protocol dates from 1987, while the AT dates from 1984.  If the JB-3000 uses any standard protocol, it's going to be the XT.